Invoke a data factory pipeline from c#
I know this question has been asked before, but the library used to constuct the answer is now obsolete or unsuported.
I'm trying to figure out how to invoke my azure data factory to run a pipeline from a c# console application.
I'm wanting to use Azure.ResourceManager.DataFactory but chatGPT keeps providing the wrong answers and google doesn't help. The MS documentation is useless!

I just want to put the HTTP trigger option out there for you. If you can not get the SDK's to work, simply spin up an httpClient and use the system assigned managed identity for the Function/WebApp/"whatever you are using" to authenticate your request.
This of course require you to set the appropriate RBAC on your identity, but I assume you would have to do that any way :)
POST
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mySubId/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/myDataFactory/pipelines/copyPipeline/createRun?api-version=2017-03-01-preview

